# Links to UDF in Excel only work with 'tilde' paths

Tags: excel

I use many functions from an XLA Add-In in the XLSTART folder. Recently they all stopped working and Excel, instead of showing just the function in the formula, shows the full path to the XLA.

Example: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\xlstart\UDFs.xla'!myFunction()

It also, and more importantly, no longer calculates, showing #NAME?, as if it cannot find the file at that location. The file, however, never moved and is still there. I finally narrowed down the issue to the fact that it's not recognizing the folder with the full path name. If I instead enter 'C:\Progra~1\Micros~3\Office12\xlstart\UDFs.xla'!myFunction() using tildes, the formula works.

Any ideas why that would happen and how to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if you can re-point it to the correct file using the Data>Edit Links dialog. Of course, that would only work for one workbook at a time. Hopefully somebody has seen this before.

Comment: I can. I can also use a macro to replace the links in all files. However, I have these files in many locations on many computers. It would not be very practical to do that. Seems to be a Windows issue more than Excel link issue.

Comment: This is happening on more than one computer?

Comment: Not yet. I am in the midst of distributing a program that uses these UDFs. If I start having this issue on the 40 other computers, I'll be up the creek. I would love to know what's causing it, at least, to know if I can assume it will be an isolated incident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I got the answer. I was starting Excel using a program that finds the Excel app location using a registry entry that uses the tilde path. Excel therefore converted it's link to the appPath using Tildes. If I start these Excel files directly, the links work okay.

Thank you.